# How to select NEWID() for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

SELECT is like this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  
     Header.EntryGUID,
     Header.ImportDate
FROM table_Name Header
WHERE Header.ID 
ORDER BY EntryGUID
```

OUTPUT is:

```
EntryGUID   -------------------------------------------------  ImportDate

B7FFC239-2370-4E65-A184-7F2DD18A196E-----2015-02-24 00:00:00.000

B7FFC239-2370-4E65-A184-7F2DD18A196E-----2015-03-15 00:00:00.000
```

My question is how to select for second row NEWID()

Comment: Please fix your title. Using all caps makes it look like you ARE YELLING AT US.

Comment: "how to select for second row NEWID()"  I just don't understand what you are asking.  Can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with window functions:

```
select ImportDate,
       case when row_number() over(partition by EntryGUID order by ImportDate) = 1
            then EntryGUID else newid() end as EntryGUID
from(
SELECT DISTINCT  
     Header.EntryGUID,
     Header.ImportDate
FROM table_Name Header
WHERE Header.ID = 'variable')t
```

This will order rows by date, leave first row untouched and replace other rows with new guids.